# Android+PhoneGap FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cordova, adt

I'm building an Android with PhoneGap 1.4 app in Mac OSX 10.7.3 using Eclipse. This is a very simple app, the html is simple and has no JS. 
I get a FATAL EXCEPTION, here is the logcat:

```
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start          activity ComponentInfo{com.myphone.test/com.myphone.test.MyPhone}:   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:907)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:82)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:62)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap$1.run(DroidGap.java:518)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4170)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.loadUrlIntoView(DroidGap.java:494)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.phonegap.DroidGap.loadUrl(DroidGap.java:460)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.myphone.test.MyPhone.onCreate(MyPhone.java:11)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-08 15:04:29.920: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  ... 11 more
```

And the manifest file:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyPhone"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
        <intent-filter> </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
</application>
```

If someone could help me would be great :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` make sure you aren't trying to load a resource that isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the protip :)
Yes, indeed I was trying to load a XML plugin config file that was not there.


/res/xml/plugins.xml

Many thanks code bro :)